# Error with maxreceivedmessagesize even when my file is small

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi I am new here and I have found many issues related with maxReceivedMessageSize, but I would like to understand in detail why happened.

My file is a pdf (size=3MB) and I had configured maxReceivedMessageSize="10485000" (10mb), so it should be enough but no, I had to change the value to  104850000 (100 MB) and in this way worked.

Why the error was thrown? does the size of the file change in the message that I send to the service? as I mentioned with the new value works but I would like to understand why I need a value of 100 MB if my file is just 3MB

I send this object to the service

```
 public class Document
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DocumentName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public sbyte[] DataBytes { get; set; }
}
```

And it is the method I use to send the file:

```
       private static void SendFile()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                SendFile.LoadDocument.Document document = new SendFile.LoadDocument.Document();
                document.DocumentName = "MyFile_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".pdf";
                document.DataBytes = stream.ToSbytes();

                LoadDocumentClient service = new LoadDocumentClient();
                service.LoadDocuments(document);
            }
        }
        catch (CommunicationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and add the relevant code as text.

Comment: The unit of maxReceivedMessageSize is byte, 10485000 bytes is about 10MB, 104850000 is about 100MB, is your PDF less than 10MB?

Comment: yes my PDF is only 3MG

Comment: Sorry,I don’t know what unit you mean by MG. Does MG mean GB?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake I meant MB, my file is 3 MB, for that reason I don't understand why if the maxReceivedMessageSize="10485000" (10 MB) I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with maxReceivedMessageSize, it is caused by converting the stream to sbyte, you can try to directly transfer the stream type file.

```
 var stream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
 ServiceReference1.CalculatorClient Client = new ServiceReference1.CalculatorClient();
 Client.LoadDocuments(stream);
```